# Can I filter my Coverity filename results using something like a regex?

Tags: regex, coverity-prevent, coverity

I'm working with Coverity and I'd like to filter my filename results in my view in a regex style.

Is there anything more sophisticated available in coverity apart from:

```
? - Any single character
* - Any group of characters
```

Which is somewhat limiting, is there any support for regex style filtering? (I can't find anything that works)

Comment: Any particular reason for the -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use components.  Define a component with a filename regex and then filter by that component to view only filenames that match.

Comment: Was hoping for regex support but this will do for now! Thanks.